# Howto build Qt 5.9.2 on macos sierra with Homebrew gcc 6.4.0

Tags: macos, qt, gcc

For a legacy project I need Qt to be compiled static with **gcc 6.4** on **macos sierra**. So I installed *gcc@6* and *Qt source for 5.9.2* and started with `configure -platform macx-g++` instead of *macx-clang*. I have added all symbolic links to */usr/local/bin* where homebrew puts the gcc links into (so g++ points to g++-6) and added the */usr/local/bin* path upfront to *$PATH*.

Alas, running the Qt configure call to build qmake ends with

> Project ERROR: failed to parse default search paths from compiler output

Can anyone give me a hint, what's going wrong?

Cheers

Comment: I ran into this today as well with Qt 5.9.3 on Mac OS High Sierra.  I set the QMAKE_MAC_SDK path (not sure if it was required or not) to: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.13.sdk
and then instead of setting the configure options, I only set --prefix and it seemed to work.  I don't know why using the others didn't work at all.

Comment: So I spoke too soon.  It compiles but now I get:  Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "AVFVideoRendererControl::staticMetaObject", referenced from:
      AVFMediaPlayerService::releaseControl(QMediaControl*) in avfmediaplayerservice.o
  "AVFVideoRendererControl::AVFVideoRendererControl(QObject*)", referenced from:
      AVFMediaPlayerService::requestControl(char const*) in avfmediaplayerservice.o

Comment: I posted another issue I had with AVMediaPlayer while compiling after getting past this issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47848765/qt-compile-mac-os-undefined-symbols-avfmediaplayerservice-avfvideorenderercontro